# Can't see other virtual machine on Internal Network

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, ping

I have two Windows XP virtual machines running on Windows 7 Virtual PC.  Both are connected to the "Internal Network" network adaptor.

I can't ping one VM from the other.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first suggest examining the settings of the Windows Firewall on each of the systems.

Second, are you sure that the Win 7 Virtual PC allows this?

Comment: VPC does allow this, the adaptors have to be both set to Internal though. Firewalls is probably the cause. Nice rep (1337)!